# How to install CloudFoundry on local server

Tags: cloud-foundry

I know that CF is made for running on multiple cloud services for one unified view of an microservice app. However, I would like to install and run the cloud foundry on my CentOS local server. In other wourds I would like to setup my private "cloud" on one server running CF as a microservice-based app container.

**How can I install CF on my local server so that later I could deploy some microservices on the local server for educational purposes, for microservice ping pong testing?**

Comment: If you have vagrant and virtualbox, you can use PCFDev: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev

Answer (score 15):

## Setup CF (Cloud Foundry)

** UPDATE **
Probably the easiest way is PCF Dev https://pivotal.io/pcf-dev BOSH Lite gives you more options, but for most people just trying out CF I would recommend PCF Dev.

Easiest way is to deploy CF using BOSH Lite. You will probably need 16gb of ram.

**Install Vagrant**

```
gem install vagrant
```

**Download BOSH Lite**

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite
```

**Start up BOSH Lite**

```
cd bosh-lite
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

**Target Bosh Lite**

```
bosh target 192.168.50.4 lite
```

username/password: **admin/admin**

**Add needed routes**

```
bin/add-route
```

**Download the Stemcell**

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/bosh-warden-stemcells/bosh-stemcell-3147-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent.tgz
```

**Install BOSH CLI**

```
gem install bosh_cli --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

**Upload the stemcell that BOSH Lite CF uses**

```
bosh upload stemcell bosh-stemcell-3147-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent.tgz
```

**Download CF**

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release.git --recursive
```

**Generate the CF BOSH Lite manifest**

```
scripts/generate-bosh-lite-dev-manifest
```

**Create, Upload and Deploy release**

```
bosh create release --force && bosh upload release && bosh -n deploy
```

^^^ This will take awhile ^^^

---

## Work with CF

**Install CF CLI**
See instructions here:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

**Login to CF**

```
cf login -a https://api.bosh-lite.com --skip-ssl-validation -u admin -p admin
```

**Create an org**

```
cf create-org org
```

**Create a space**

```
cf create-space space -o org
```

**Target org and space**

```
cf target -o org -s space
```

**Push App**

```
cf push
```

That should do it!

Comment: I get an error when I type the "bosh upload ..." bit saying "Please choose target file first"

Comment: Yes sorry I left that bit out, it is in the bosh-lite github repo, but I should add it to the instructions.

    **bosh target <hostname or ip> <give it any name>**

If you are using bosh lite then do:

   **bosh target 192.168.50.4 lite**

basically you need to let it know where bosh is

Comment: After targeting it will ask you for a username/password, for bosh lite it will be admin/admin. you can find more info at: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite

Comment: Oh, thanks! I eventually figured that out, but I've run into some more weird issues trying to actually deploy the server. However, I think that my issues may have surpassed the scope of this ticket, but thanks anyways!

Comment: sometime cf create-org org doesn't work..when you do cf org it doesn't show the org created...then in that case you can use the pivotal site..login to it and create a trial org and you can create space to it ..

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use the new [PCF Dev](https://pivotal.io/pcf-dev).
This runs well on machines with at least 8GB of RAM. 
Download and start it as described in the [documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/#installing)

After a few minutes you have a full working CF on your local machine having MySQL, Redis and RabbitMQ as marketplace services.
Currently Apps Manager or Spring Cloud Services are missing but according to [here](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/meet-pcf-dev-your-ticket-to-running-cloud-foundry-locally) these will be added in future releases as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up that the workflow for setting up a bosh-lite has changed: http://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite.html

I'd also suggest using [cf-deployment](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment) instead of cf-release.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to enjoy Stackato locally is to check Stackato Cloud Foundry Micro Cloud - http://docs.stackato.com/admin/setup/microcloud.html. You just need a virtualbox, then download the MicroCloud VM, run it in VirtualBox and voila you can start deploying microservices.

With a decent Internet connection, you will be enjoying Cloud Foundry in like 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

To deploy CF on a single server for educational purposes you may want to try out [deploying CloudFoundry using BOSH Lite](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/boshlite/) as described in the docs. Your server should at least have 16GB of RAM.